# Aggregating numbers based on a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have a table :

```
A | B | C|  D
2   4   5  01
3   3   1  02
12  1   13 03
```

I want the logic `A + B - C` to be grouped by column `D`. However, i want the value of `A+B-C` to be carried on to the next grouping. so, output table:

```
D | Total
```

01    1
   02    6
   03    6

Logic for

```
01 : 2 + 4 - 5 = 1
02 : 1(from 01) + 3+3 -1  = 6
03 : 6 + 12 + 1 -13 = 6
```

I was trying to find the result of the logic grouping on D. But i am stuck on how to use the last groupings result.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Column D specifies the ordering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a cumulative sum:

```
select t.*, sum(a + b - c) over (order by d) as total
from t;
```

I think `d` is determining the ordering of the results.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=fdb71ff015a6073279ed8ec05ab75f6a) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: This doesnt take into account the result of the last ordered set , does it? So, if for 02 how does this 1 from 01 to it (in my example).

Comment: @Rahul . . . Of course it does.  That is how cumulative sums work.